# Failure to select an item in a Collection View, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have been working working with  `collectionViews` and `TableViews` to understand how they work but this is a little confusing. I have a  collection view hooked up to a `ViewController` together with the delegate and datasource set to itself. But on trying to use the didSelectItemAtIndexPath, nothing happens. The collection is displayed perfectly too so the datasource functions are working well.

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var timeCollectionView: UICollectionView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Register the Cell
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "DurationSelectionCollectionViewCell", bundle:nil)
        self.timeCollectionView.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DurationSelectionCollectionViewCell")

        timeCollectionView.delegate = self
        timeCollectionView.dataSource = self

        ....

}

//Selecting an item and highlighting it. 
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        timeCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it worked as long as your collectionview delegate and datasource are connected. Your problem is that you call timeCollectionView, where you want to call the generic collectionView variable that's given to you in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath declaration. I highlighted it in bold below:

func collectionView(**collectionView**: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCustomCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

}
```

Comment: Either I don't see it or something but I don't think that is available for collection Views.

Comment: my apologies, i'm going to add another answer, I might have an idea what is wrong

Comment: @Gugulethu check the updated solution I provided. I tested it in Xcode and so it should work for you.

Comment: You solution works perfectly. I actually built a project from scratch to test the collection view and it works perfect. The strange thing is in my actual project, even changing the text to collectionView as your solution showed still did not work and even on rebuilding the whole collectionVIew from scratch too. Quite strange. Anyway I will try building the whole view controller from scratch to see if anything changes. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help. Hopefully it will work for you in your project.

Comment: Turns out I had a function hide and show the keyboard with touch gesture on the view and I don't know how but it was interfering with the selection of each item in the collection. But it's all sorted.

Answer (score 1):

If `didSelectItemAtIndexPathItem:` doesn't get invoked, make sure you have `delegate` and `dataSource` set properly to your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color on selecting the item in collection view, you should subclass your `UICollectionViewCell` and override `highlighted` property.

```
class DurationSelectionCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            contentView.backgroundColor = highlighted ? .grayColor() : nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and nothing is still happening! I have a break point place in the didSelectItemAtIndexPathItem and on clicking any of the cells I don't get any feedback to indicate the function is received the call.